# How to find documents without an array or smaller than 4?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Tried this, but couldn't get the desired output. I want to find documents without an array or a array smaller than 4.

```
db.collection.find({

    'text' => { '$exists' => true },
    'tags' => {

      '$or' => [

        { '$exists' => false },

        { '$lt' => ['$size', 4] }
      ]
     }
 })
```

Error is:

> unknown operator: $or

Answer (score 1):

The `$or` operator should be at the top level, with an array of complete predicates:

```
db.collection.find({
    'text' => { '$exists' => true },
    '$or' => [
        {'tags' => { '$exists' => false },
        {'tags' => { '$lt' => ['$size', 4] }
     ]
})
```